# Stop taskeng.exe from opening when running a .bat via Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have a .bat file with the below example contents that is run via Task Scheduler.

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\script.vbs > output`

How do I stop taskeng.exe from opening every time the task runs?

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler Engine (taskeng.exe) is specifically made to handle the scheduling and execution of your tasks.

[Link Here](http://www.liutilities.com/products/wintaskspro/processlibrary/taskeng/)

So it would be unwise to stop taskeng.exe from opening every time the task runs.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: So how can I schedule a .bat (and subsequent .vbs) to run without having an inconvenient black box appearing every 5 minutes? Being a Linux administrator I don't have much Windows experience, but I know that I'd do it via `cron` and it wouldn't be this hard!

Comment: Have you tried placing `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe` in the target application and `C:\script.vbs` in the parameters of the scheduled task instead of using a batch file?

Comment: @user2656114 posted screen shot for you above.

Comment: I'm piping the output to a file. Using that example the piping doesn't work and I'm shown a taskeng.exe window with the results and then it closes. Example `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe` and then `C:\script.vbs > output` as arguments.

Comment: Alright, if you don't want to display the terminal but you still want to use it's output as a logged file, then your going to have some issues. It's like saying you want to use excel to type in tables but not see excel. It's would be a headache in the long run. It's best to just use a "Scripting.FileSystemObject" to handle the output to a file.

Comment: Forgetting about the piped output at the moment, the taskeng.exe window is still being shown which was the original problem anyhow.

Comment: On Linux I would just `cron` a command like `/home/user/script.sh > output`. I'd see no window and still have a piped output. How do I do that here?